# How can i remove custom post type slug and add taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, taxonomy

## My question is about custom post rewrite url

On may page i have custom post type products

I have custom post type slug name - products and taxonomy - category.
I have urls like this:

`domain.com/custom_post_type/product_name`

but i need

`domain.com/taxonomy/product_name`

Is this acheivable?

Answer (score 0):

To change the URL in wordpress go to settings -> permalinks

You can either choose a default permalink or create your own in this case.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen